# Is there a concise, predictable way to get a column value from a cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Suppose you're trying to get values from several columns of an Android cursor (I'm using SQLite if that matters). You only care about one row, so caching the column indices doesn't make sense. You can try to get each column's value in one line like this:

```
String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));
```

But how do you detect and handle a case where a column by that name doesn't exist in the cursor?

[We know](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)) that if that happens, `cursor.getColumnIndex(name)` will return `-1`. But then what will `cursor.getString(-1)` do? Can you use `try`, and `catch` any exception thrown? It's not clear ... the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)) says,

> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

But it doesn't say anything about exceptions or other specified behavior for a `columnIndex` of -1.

My testing on a few devices indicates that you get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.
     Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Can we count on that exception being thrown?

Another way to do it is to check the index returned by `getColumnIndex()` before calling `getString(columnIndex)`:

```
columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);
if (columnIndex < 0) {
    // handle absence of column
} else {
    value = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
}
```

But using that many lines per column seems verbose, and violates the DRY principle, lending itself to careless errors in the code.

I wouldn't mind the repetition if we could extract that code into a separate method to be called for each column. But I don't see any simple way to do it, because the columns can have different types. (We could subclass [CursorWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html) and implement `getInt()`, `getString()`, etc. to do the checking we want, thus confining the repetition to a specialized utility class. Is that the best we can do?)

Another approach would be using [`getColumnIndexOrThrow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)) instead of `getColumnIndex()`. That would allow you to skip the step of saving the value of `columnIndex` and testing it, because you can count on an exception being thrown if `columnIndex` is -1 (and catch it). But that doesn't perform very well:

> If you're not sure if a column will exist or not use getColumnIndex(String) and check for -1, which is more efficient than catching the exceptions.

Any other ideas? Any thoughts on the above ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using `getColumnCount()` along with `getColumnName()` to check if the potential column name exists?

Comment: Under what circumstances is this actually a problem?  When will you have a cursor and not know precisely what columns you queried for, and thus what columns are valid and must exist?   I can't think I've ever found myself in that situation.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I agree it's not often. But generally, future-proofing an app against changes to the structure of data sources. If an app gets data from a server API or from peer devices, those sources could change. You could then change the app, but copies of the app already "out there" could stop working.

Comment: What do you mean with "handle"? Is that actually possible, and not a programming error? What do you need to do in that case?

Comment: @LarsH that's why you version apis. It's very unlikely that a data source could change that dramatically and the app still work even if you avoid this particular bug. You're trying to solve this problem at the wrong level.

Comment: @Gabe, you may be right, especially in the ideal world. However if you work in a group where you can't rely on other components (e.g. the server) fulfilling its contract -- an unfortunate reality sometimes -- you may have to decide when you want problems to become visible and when you want them to be suppressed. In that case, versioning the API won't necessarily address the problem.

Comment: @CL: How to handle the absence of an expected column would vary greatly depending on whether the data in the column is vital, and what we're doing with the data at the moment. Sometimes you'll want to ignore the problem, or substitute a default value, or show a user-visible error dialog, or log a warning, disable a feature that requires the data, or throw a fatal exception. "Is that actually possible, and not a programming error?" A missing column is probably due to *someone's* programming error, but it may be in a component you don't control (e.g. a server).

Comment: @LarsH In that case this should be problem number 5 million or so on your list.  Especially since you won't be using a cursor for anything but a database transaction.  You're absolutely worried about the wrong problem, and using the wrong solution.  You should be worried about "how do I improve the reliability of my data sources" not "how do I optimize code if a failure has already occurred".  Especially since you aren't going to get a general answer better than "throw an exception" or "return a default".  A client side pattern doesn't actually help your problem.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I think you're drawing a false dichotomy -- it doesn't have to be just addressing one problem **or** the other. I agree that the people/organizational issue of having other components adhere to their contract is important, but it's not the only important aspect of dealing with unexpected input. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming However the priority of defensive programming is a philosophical question and should probably be moved to chat.

Comment: @LarsH I practice defensive programming all the time.  This isn't it.  This is adding layers that won't actually solve your real problem, and won't solve the failure case either-  your app is unlikely to actually work if that data isn't there.  In the end, you're going to throw an exception or return a default, because doing anything else has to be done at the business logic layer.  You're not going to find any additional gains by getting fancy here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154912/discussion-between-larsh-and-gabe-sechan).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a concise, predictable way to get a column value from a
>   cursor?

I'd say yes but that would be according to good design methodology which would largely if not completely eliminate guessing/not knowing a column name. That is the column names would be known before the Cursor is created.

However, there could be situations where the column name, even if correct, could result in unanticipated results. For example where a Cursor with  joined tables which had the same column name (e.g. the often used **_id** column) or perhaps going to the realms of insanity something like `SELECT _id, _id, _id FROM cards` . In such cases renaming column name via an **AS** clause would be the solution.

> But how do you detect and handle a case where a column by that name
>   doesn't exist in the cursor?

Again, as above, a well designed project would likely fully negate the chance of this happening. If not, then use of the Cursor `getColumnCount` and `getColumnName` methods could be used to circumvent the -1, **IllegalStateException** condition e.g.

```
public boolean isColumnInCursor(String columName, Cursor csr) {
    for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        if (csr.getColumnName(i).toLowerCase().equals(columName.toLowerCase())) {
            csr.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    csr.close();
    return false;
}
```

An example usage being :-

```
    Cursor csr = ex001db.getAisleAndShopsWithUniqueIDColumns();
    String test_column = "Fred";
    if (!ex001db.isColumnInCursor("Fred", csr)) {
        Log.d("OUCH","Column " + test_column + " not in Cursor");
    }
    test_column = DBHlpr001.AISLENAMECOLUMN;
    if (!ex001db.isColumnInCursor(test_column, csr)) {
        Log.d("OUCH","Column " + test_column + " not in Cursor");
    } else {
        Log.d("NOT OUCH","Column " + test_column + " is in Cursor");
    }
    csr.close();
```

with output from the above being :-

```
09-20 13:25:35.163 4217-4217/? D/OUCH: Column Fred not in Cursor
09-20 13:25:35.164 4217-4217/? D/NOT OUCH: Column aislename is in Cursor
```

> I wouldn't mind the repetition if we could extract that code into a
>   separate method to be called for each column. But I don't see any
>   simple way to do it, because the columns can have different types. (We
>   could subclass CursorWrapper and implement getInt(), getString(), etc.
>   to do the checking we want, thus confining the repetition to a
>   specialized utility class. Is that the best we can do?)

I'm not really sure if the above code (`isColumnInCursor` method) would suit your requirements although I'm pretty sure it meets the single seperate method, at least for detecting the missing column condition.

> Any other ideas? Any thoughts on the above ideas?

The above!?